# How to open a new tab in same session

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, tabs

How to open a new tab in same session, I have already tried common solution given by others but its not working.

I am trying in chrome browser.

My project is in java

Comment: My project is in java, sorry forgot to mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a **`New Blank TAB`** you can use the following line of code :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");
```

To open a **`New TAB with url`** you can use the following line of code :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
```

Comment: Just to inform you this link is opened in 3rd tab, script also opens 2nd tab as a blank tab

Comment: First line of code is to open a _NEW blank TAB_ only. Second line of code is to open a _NEW TAB with a url_ .  These are 2 options. Use only the option you require in your script.

Comment: Hi, My login to gmail code was working properly till the time I added above mentioned code but since the time I have added this code my login code is not working.

Comment: This block of code hava no relation with your login code. For your login code query can you raise a new question please?

Comment: @SaketBelokar in which tab you are opening the login page. edit your question by adding your code and also add the errors which you are facing.

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes You were right the code for new tab opening had no relation, i was getting button not clickable issue, dont know why, so just updated Xpath of button once & it started working li earlier.

Comment: @RanjithKasu, Thanks for your inputs, I was just getting button not clickable issue, dont know why, so just updated Xpath of button once & it started working li earlier.