# How to open new tab on Chrome browser using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've tried the following solutions but it didn't work, I am using Selenium 3.9.1 and Chrome v66.0.3, do we have any other alternate solutions:

```
Solution 1:
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "/t");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://google.com");
Solution 2:
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718024/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-same-session)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to open links in new tabs is by simulating key-board shortcuts. The following hold true in FFX, Chrome & IE

1. Ctrl+t will open a blank new tab, and switch focus to it.
2. Holding Ctrl, then clicking the link will open the link in a new tab but leave focus on the existing tab.
3. Holding Ctrl AND Shift, then clicking will open the link in a new tab AND move focus onto the new tab.
4. Ctrl+w will close the current tab and switch focus to the last open tab (although note that Ctrl+W i.e. Ctrl+Shift+w will close ALL tabs!)

Selenium doesn't (currently) have any concept of tabs within a browser window, so in order to open the tab and then test it you HAVE to use option 3.

Try something like this:

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");  
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

P.S
Look at here for this bug -> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5462

Comment: I think I have seen `Ctrl + T` work in Protractor tests

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `JavaScriptExecutor` to open a new window and switch to it?

Now sure about the Java syntax, but in Protractor it may be something like this

```
browser.executeScript('window.open()').then(function () {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            var secondWindow = handles[1];
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            browser.switchTo().window(secondWindow).then(function () {
                browser.get('https://google.com');
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");

    Set<String> tabs = new HashSet<String>();

    tabs = driver.getWindowHandles();

    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>(tabs);

    driver.switchTo().window(li.get(1));
    driver.get("https://www.fb.com");
```